# About the events in Morocco?

Tags: mission-impossible-rogue-nation, mission-impossible

In *Mission:Impossible - Rogue Nation*,

Ethan Hunt and the IMF (Impossible Mission Force) are involved with The Syndicate, a secretive terrorist organization. In its course of action against the Syndicate, the IMF team has to go to Morocco to perform its usual *infiltration scene*. There, they were told

> by MI6 undercover agent Ilsa Faust that a file containing the names of all Syndicate's agents, its only weak point,

is located in a very secure building in Morocco. My understanding at that point was that it was a Syndicate building.

Later, we learn that

> the memory device stolen in Morocco actually contained a list of bank accounts that could fund the Syndicate and make it nearly untouchable for decades. All the previous events of the movie were set in motion by Solomon Lane, the Syndicate mastermind, for Ethan Hunt to steal the document for him.

So, it seems to me that it is finally not a Syndicate building.

**My question:** what is the building in Morocco and who owns it?

Answer (score 2):

The building in Morocco is a **power station**. Beneath the power station was the **secure underwater server**.

The building was not owned by the Syndicate. I believe it was actually owned by the government (Someone please correct me if I am mistaken).

Comment: I don't believe the film ever explicitly states who controls the building. But it's definitely not the syndicate, otherwise Solomon wouldn't need them to retrieve it. We are never told if it's completely government operated or just a third party that will host files for anyone (including governments).